# How much sunlight would 'fit' through a fibre optic cable?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

Say a parabolic mirror were used to focus the full sunlight spectrum into a single strand of optical fibre. Assuming ideal conditions (perfect reflecting surface, focal point smaller than diameter of fibre core, perfect orientation towards the sun), what sized mirror could the fibre cope with before melting?

Alternately how many strands of fibre would be required to pipe in the equivalent of a 1 square metre skylight at high noon?

Comment: Depends entirely on the size of your optical fiber. There is no limit to how large you can make them. Are we talking about a 100/140um multimode fiber or an 8-10um single mode fiber? There is at least one company that does this kind of thing. Did you look at their products?

Comment: As for a back of the envelop calculation of how to focus solar energy into a spot: the size of the focal spot is about 1/120 the focal length of a concentrating lens or mirror, so if your fiber has 100um diameter, then the max. focal length would be  about 12mm. The max. diameter of the lens would then be given by the max. angle under which internal reflection happens aka "acceptance angle" which is most often expressed as a numerical aperture. For most fibers this is 0.2-0.3, i.e. the max. lens diameter in this case is 2.4-3.6mm, which will certainly not melt the fiber.